# Maximum and Minimum possible Ratios between number of nodes in a path graph and number of nodes in its full independent set

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose, we consider a **path** graph (straight line, no branching) with an arbitrary number of nodes **n**. Suppose we have two cases where independent set (IS) is always full: 1. IS is maximum possible size 2. IS in full but not maximum possible size.

- Case 1:

Suppose, we consider a maximum possible independent set for that graph where **i** is the number of nodes in that set.
Is there a constant that denotes what the minimum possible ratio **i/n** is such that there is no such path graph where that ratio would be less than this constant?

If so, what's the name and value of this constant? My math background is very limited: I tried searching for it, but didn't find anything.

- Case 2:

Similarly to Case 1, what's the **minimum** possible ratio between a number of nodes in the **minimal** possible **full** independent set (i.e., such a configuration of an independent set where it's not a maximum independent set, and yet no more nodes can be added to it: E.g., for a path graph of length 5, [1, 0, 1, 0, 1] is maximum possible (3 nodes) VS. [0, 1, 0, 1, 0] is a minimum possible full (2 nodes) independent set) and a number of nodes in a path graph **i/n**?

---

Basically, I am trying to find what the ratio bounds are for when we cannot add any more nodes to an independent set.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The size of a maximum independent set is $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ (take every other node), so the ratio is $n/\lceil n/2 \rceil$, which is $2$ if $n$ is even and in the interval $[1,2)$ if $n$ is odd.

---

Update after you added Case 2 to the question: The minimum size of a maximal independent set is called the [independent domination number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set#Independent_domination) of the graph.
For a path on $n$ nodes, this number is $\lceil n/3 \rceil$ by taking every third vertex.  The ratio $n/\lceil n/3 \rceil$ is $3$ if $n$ is a multiple of $3$ and in the interval $[1,3)$ otherwise.

In summary, for a path on $n$ nodes the ratio of the size of a maximal independent set and the number of nodes is always in the interval $[1,3]$.

Comment: But what are the bounds for when it's odd?